# DELETE method PHP

Tags: php, http

I'm using `php://input` to retrieve parameters in POST/DELETE method.
The issue is that in POST requests I'm able to use `php://input` as many times as possible, whereas in DELETE Method I'm only able to use it once and after that this `php://input` returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's documented](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.